# Returning ActiveRecord::Relation as json to an ajax call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, activerecord

There is probably a simple solution to my problem but intensive googling has came up with nothing.

I've got an ajax call:

```
$.get(path,{ section_id: "a", field_id: "b"})
 .done(function(data) {alert(data);})
 .fail(function() { alert("error"); });
```

this ajax call goes to the specified controller and executes a query the returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object. So far, so good. 
Now, what i want to do is return this ActiveRecord::Relation object as json to the done function. How can i do that?
Thanks to all helpers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to return an object from a relation and not the active record class. In your controller, you should render your object in the appropriate format, something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @your_object}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the criteria hash used in the ActiveRecord::Relation object you can do that :

@relation.where_values_hash.to_json

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this

```
@post = Post.where(id: params[:id])
# @post at the moment is an AR::Relation
render json: @post, status: :ok
```

will actually just return the record serialized as JSON. You can actually test this out in the rails console by doing the following:

```
@record = YourModel.where(some_condition: some_parameter)
@record.class #=> ActiveRecord::Relation
@json_record = @record.to_json
@json_record.class #=> String
# @json_record will be the JSON representation of whatever the Relation fetched for you.
```